# add or modify the items of the template

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

BackPack PageManager add templates to pages how do you do it?
I would like to add or modify the items of the template drop-down where should I go to Backpack?
[image]

Any fields defined here will show up after the standard page fields:
    | - select template
    | - page name (only seen by admins)
    | - page title
    | - page slug
    */

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the README file on Github](https://github.com/laravel-backpack/pagemanager#install) for this package. Under Installation it instructs you to create a `PageTemplates.php` file. That's where you can create new templates. To create a new template just create a new method in that file, and inside it add the fields you want the template to have.